# How to choose file locally

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I got this code and I can't understand how I can select file in code. I need to skip the selection menu. The file which I need to select is always in the same folder with this file. The code is used to get two CSV file columns and put in arrays and then rotate frames.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0">
  <div id="hidden_div">
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" id="the_form">
      <input type="file" id="the_file" required="required" accept=".csv"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Rotate!"/>
    </form>
    <div id="file_info"></div>
    <div id="list"></div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr=[];
var urls=[];
var times=[];
var idx=0;
var currentFrame = "f"
var nextFrame = "g"
var firstEverRotation = true

 function fileInfo(e){             // CSV file selector
   var file = e.target.files[0];
     return;
  }
 function handleFileSelect(){   // Function for CSV file parsing and filling arrays
  var file = document.getElementById("the_file").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(file) {  // Read the CSV file and split it into arrays
              var content = file.target.result; // Results from the FileReader
              var rows = file.target.result.split(/[\r\n|\n]+/);  // Split the contents of the file into rows based on carriage returns
              for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++){  // For each row, split the contents into columns separated by commas (i starts at 1 to skip column headers in CSV)
                arr = rows[i].split(',');
                for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){ // Split the URL's and times into separate arrays
                 urls.push(arr[j]);
                 j++;
                 times.push(arr[j]);
                }
              }
          showUrl();
          };
  reader.readAsText(file);
  };



</script>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Shroud try this

```js
/*
filedrag.js - HTML5 File Drag & Drop demonstration
*/
(function() {

 // getElementById
 function $id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
 }


 // output information
 function Output(msg) {
  var m = $id("messages");
  m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
 }


 // file drag hover
 function FileDragHover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
 }


 // file selection
 function FileSelectHandler(e) {

  // cancel event and hover styling
  FileDragHover(e);

  // fetch FileList object
  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

  // process all File objects
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
   ParseFile(f);
  }

 }


 // output file information
 function ParseFile(file) {

  Output(
   "<p>File information: <strong>" + file.name +
   "</strong> type: <strong>" + file.type +
   "</strong> size: <strong>" + file.size +
   "</strong> bytes</p>"
  );

 }


 // initialize
 function Init() {

  var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
   filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
   submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

  // file select
  fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

  // is XHR2 available?
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (xhr.upload) {

   // file drop
   filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
   filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
   filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
   filedrag.style.display = "block";

   // remove submit button
   submitbutton.style.display = "none";
  }

 }

 // call initialization file
 if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
  Init();
 }


})();
```

```css
/*
Styles for HTML5 File Drag & Drop demonstration
*/
body
{
 font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Helvetica, freesans, sans-serif;
 font-size: 90%;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background-color: #fff;
}

h1, h2
{
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: normal;
}

h2
{
 font-size: 1.3em;
}

legend
{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #333;
}

#filedrag
{
 display: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1em 0;
 margin: 1em 0;
 color: #555;
 border: 2px dashed #555;
 border-radius: 7px;
 cursor: default;
}

#filedrag.hover
{
 color: #f00;
 border-color: #f00;
 border-style: solid;
 box-shadow: inset 0 3px 4px #888;
}

img
{
 max-width: 100%;
}

pre
{
 width: 95%;
 height: 8em;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 padding: 1px 2px;
 margin: 0 0 1em auto;
 border: 1px inset #666;
 background-color: #eee;
 overflow: auto;
}

#messages
{
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin: 1em 0;
 border: 1px solid #999;
}

#progress p
{
 display: block;
 width: 240px;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 margin: 2px 0;
 border: 1px inset #446;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #eee url("progress.png") 100% 0 repeat-y;
}

#progress p.success
{
 background: #0c0 none 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#progress p.failed
{
 background: #c00 none 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>HTML5 File Drag &amp; Drop API</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>HTML5 File Drag &amp; Drop API</h1>

<form id="upload" action="index.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<legend>HTML File Upload</legend>

<input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />

<div>
 <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
 <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
 <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
</div>

<div id="submitbutton">
 <button type="submit">Upload Files</button>
</div>

</fieldset>

</form>

<div id="messages">
<p>Status Messages</p>
</div>
<script src="filedrag.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mate i need to skip the selection menu with your code i still need to drag file . I just need to select file in the code without asking to select it. Like when i load my html file it instantly rotate webpages from csv file .

Comment: Plz visit this website http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.html , And This method is not really a library OR a program, but for ad hoc conversions you can

put the HTML for a table in a text file called something.xls
open it with a spreadsheet
save it as CSV.
I know this works with Excel, and I believe I've done it with the OpenOffice spreadsheet.

But you probably would prefer a Perl or Ruby script...