# Unable to pick a file on Angular

Tags: angular, angular11

for some reason I am not able to pick a file.

here is my code

```
    <button mat-stroked-button type="button" (click)="filePicker.click()" >Pick Image</button>
    <input type="file" #filePicker>
```

No matter which button I pick it does not work. I also don't get a an error which is weird

I tried the StackOverflow question but I didn't have any luck::

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914566/how-to-choose-file-locally
```

here is the project repository:
https://github.com/casas1010/mean-project

this is the files for the page that I am having issues with:
https://github.com/casas1010/mean-project/tree/main/src/app/posts/post-create

this is the documentation from angular::
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/

idk why its not working :(

Comment: You will have to be a bit more specific. What error are you getting? The code you have here seems to work just fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-brcmiw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: it works now. i restartedd my computer... so weird